# What to ignore in a Mercurial .hgignore for a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mercurial

I created a hello world app with `rails HelloWorld` command. I ended up with many directories:

- app
- config
- db
- doc
- lib
- log
- public
- script
- test
- tmp
- vendor

Should all this be under sources control? What would be a good default `.hgignore` file for a Ruby on Rails app folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `log/*`
- `tmp/*`
- your dev database under `db`

can be ignored to start with.

Answer (score 8):

```
.bundle
db/*.sqlite3
log/*.log
tmp/*

.DS_Store
.orig
```

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that if you've typed it by hand it should be in source control.  If there are some scaffolding files that you didn't type but that can't be easily generated by your build system and don't often change, add them too.  Avoid adding files that can be generated from other added files and non-mergeable files that change often.

Comment: As a note, the rails team recommends versioning the generated schema